# HERE maps removeEventListener doesn't work

Tags: javascript, maps, here-api

I'm trying to remove an "addEventListerner" from the map, but it is not working There is my code:

```js
function dbltapzoom(){
    alert("Remove");
}

 map.addEventListener('pointerdown', function (evt) {
         var coord = map.screenToGeo(evt.currentPointer.viewportX,
         evt.currentPointer.viewportY);

         polygonStroke.setGeometry(coord);
         polygonStroke.setVisibility(true);
         locationVertices.push(polygonStroke);
         map.addObject(polygonStroke);    
},false);

map.addEventListener('dbltap', function () { 
          map.removeEventListener('pointerdown',dbltapzoom,false);
});
```

Honestly, I don't know how to make this work. Any help and explanation what I'm doing wrong would be nice . Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only remove the same registered listener. Like as you have registered to map lister `handlepointerdown` on `pointerdown`, you can only remove `handlepointerdown`, you cannot remove `dbltapzoom` within the same listener

```
function dbltapzoom(){
    alert("Remove");
}

function handlepointerdown(evt) {
         var coord = map.screenToGeo(evt.currentPointer.viewportX,
         evt.currentPointer.viewportY);

         polygonStroke.setGeometry(coord);
         polygonStroke.setVisibility(true);
         locationVertices.push(polygonStroke);
         map.addObject(polygonStroke);    
}

 map.addEventListener('pointerdown', handlepointerdown,false);

map.addEventListener('dbltap', function () { 
          map.removeEventListener('pointerdown',handlepointerdown,false);
});
```